# How do I put a php file inside a div class?

Tags: php, html

> Hi good day! I don't really know how to post here since its my first time here. Please don't hesitate to teach me the basics. Anyways here is my code.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .box{
    width: 450px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
  }
  .box-img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .box h1{
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 100;
  }
  .box h5{
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 100;
  }
  .box p{
    text-align: justify;
  }
  ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .box li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .box li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 60px;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  }
  .box li a:hover{
    color: #b9b9b9;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Personal WebSite</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <img src="profile.jpg" alt="" class="box-img">
    <h1>DarkCode</h1>
    <h5>Web Devloper - Web Designer</h5>
    <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> This is the php file that I want to include in the box (menu.php)

```
  <?php

class Fruit{
    public $name;
    public $color;

    function __construct($name, $color){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->color = $color;
    }
    function get_name(){
        return $this->name;
    }
    function __destruct(){

        echo  "<h1>The fruit is {$this->name} and the color is {$this->color}.</h1>";
    }
}

$apple = new Fruit("Apple", "red");
//echo $apple->get_name();
?>
```

Running this code will display the echo statement outside of the box. How do I put that statement inside the div class?

[This is the screenshot of the results of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kqcu.png)

Comment: Check where the `menu.php` is? Cause, when you are including `menu.php` you can just call it if it is with index.html

Comment: all of the files are in the same directory

Comment: Do you want to show `$apple->get_name()` inside `ul`/`li` class?

Comment: I want to show 'echo  "<h1>The fruit is {$this->name} and the color is {$this->color}.</h1>";' inside the div class while also still being part of the destruct class

Comment: Please share more details - for example, why did you put some `echo` in the destructor of the class? Why not call some method on that class instead - destructors will not run until the very end of the lifecycle of that object

Comment: It's a requirement for my class and I couldn't think of any other way to implement it. My professor told me to apply both a constructor and deconstructor in a site. I'm just a newbie in php so I don't know much. @NicoHaase

Comment: Has your professor told you **why** to do that? Working with PHP for more than ten years, I've only seldom used a destructor, and I would never use it to echo anything - just because you cannot control where this would be printed

Comment: I honestly don't know. My professor just told us to design a webpage while integrating constructor and deconstructor. We did some exercises that show that a deconstructor can echo something so I thought it would be a good idea to do just that. But I found it very hard to integrate the design so I went here as I couldn't find an answer to how its done. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current method should display the statement inside `<div class="box"> </div>`.
But if the contents are out of the box it may be due to some problem in your CSS.

Could your share your CSS code and maybe a screenshot of how your content appears.

================== After Edit ======================

The first fix I made was: I used `<?php include "./menu.php"; ?>` instead of `<?php include("menu.php"); ?>`

The second is when you echo it gets Correctly displayed within the div.
The __destruct() function, is automatically called at the end of the script, and the contents of that are only displayed out of the box. uncommented `echo $apple->get_name();`

[image]

Wrapping up, __destruct() is used for recovering the heap space allocated during the lifetime of an object, closing file or database connections, and releasing network resources.

**If you really want to display the H1** I made this change.

```
<?php

    $des=""; 

    class Fruit
    {
        public $name;
        public $color;

        function __construct($name, $color)
        {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->color = $color;
        }
        function get_name()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }
        function __destruct()
        {

            global $des;
            $des = "<h1>The fruit is {$this->name} and the color is {$this->color}.</h1>";
            
        }
    }

    $apple = new Fruit("Apple", "red");
    echo $apple->get_name();
    unset($apple);
    echo $des;    
?>
```

[image: Updated Image]

Helpful links:
[PHP unset](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_var_unset.asp)

Comment: I'll edit my post to include the css file and a screenshot. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you for answering! This helped me a lot! One more question. Is there any way I can display the echo in the destruct() inside the box?

Comment: Thank you so much! You answered my question perfectly. Hope you have a nice day!

Comment: My pleasure @Andre'Bella !

Answer (score 1):

You shuld try following source code

```
<div class="box">
<img src="profile.jpg" alt="" class="box-img">
<h1>DarkCode</h1>
<h5>Web Devloper - Web Designer</h5>
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<ul><li><?php echo $apple->get_name();?></li></ul>
```

And, you can add `<?php echo $apple->get_name();?>` somewhere else also.
Just add `<h4><?php echo $apple->get_name();?></h4>` You can add whereever you want to add it. `<label><?php echo $apple->get_name();?></label>`

Comment: Thank you for answering! But I want to put the statement found in the destruct() inside the box. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is "this"? Please explain what you've changed, and why. I would assume that calling `get_name` does not return the same string the destructor echos